# Merge cells with same words

Tags: google-apps-script

I created an array containing multiple rows and columns.
In column B, I have the type of vegetables, and in column c, the varieties.
In the array, there is an automatic sorting which is carried out in column B then column c.

Is it possible to merge automatically the cells of column B containing the same type?

I just know how to merge a range with :

```
var range1 = sheet.getRange("b4:b9");
range1.merge();
```

[A test array here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OlaAWvcRAz5TTPEFy49i0k-mRFsILXTfiNVOgQ2W5ko/edit?usp=sharing)

Cordially.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. I would start by writing a function which is triggered `on edit` and inspects the event range, along with the values left, right, above, and below it (probably also the diagonals). Where it finds duplicate values, it then checks the ranges can be merged, and if so, merges them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this sample script? I think that there are several answers for this situation, so please think of this as one of them. The flow of this script is as follows.

#### Flow :

1. Retrieve values of column B.
2. Retrieve the number of duplication values.
3. Merge cells.

#### Sample script :

```
function myFunction() {
  var start = 4; // Start row number for values.
  var c = {};
  var k = "";
  var offset = 0;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  // Retrieve values of column B.
  var data = ss.getRange(start, 2, ss.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().filter(String);

  // Retrieve the number of duplication values.
  data.forEach(function(e){c[e[0]] = c[e[0]] ? c[e[0]] + 1 : 1;});

  // Merge cells.
  data.forEach(function(e){
    if (k != e[0]) {
      ss.getRange(start + offset, 2, c[e[0]], 1).merge();
      offset += c[e[0]];
    }
    k = e[0];
  });
}
```

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- This sample script supposes that the values of column B is sorted.
- From your shared spreadsheet, it supposes that there are the values for merging cells at column B.
- In your shared spreadsheet, the order of sorted values is `Composées, Cucurbitacées, Légumineuses, Liliacées, Solanacées`. On the other hand, the order of "Wish" is `Composées, Cucurbitacées, Légumineuses, Solanacées, Liliacées`.

  - I couldn't understand the difference logic between `Liliacées, Solanacées` and `Solanacées, Liliacées`.
  - In this sample script, it uses the order of sorted values.

#### Reference :

- [merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge())

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

### Edit 1 :

For your next question, I think that the following flow can achieve what you want. But I think that there may be other solution.

1. Add values by an user.
2. Break the merged cells using `breakApart()`.

   - For example, it merges cells of "A1:A3" which have the values of `"sample", "sample", "sample"`. When this merged cell is broken using `breakApart()`, each value of "A1:A3" retrieved by `getValues()` becomes `[["sample"],[""],[""]]`.
3. Fill the empty cells created by `breakApart()`.
4. Sort the cells.
5. Run the sample script on my answer.

#### Reference :

- [breakApart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#breakApart())

### Edit 2 :

#### Usage of breakApart():

If you want to break "B1:B", please use as follows.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
ss.getRange("B1:B").breakApart()
```

Comment: Hello and thank you @Tanaike for your help.

You understand very well my request, the table is well sorted in column B then in column C. Your code works very well.
I might have to take car brands to make it easier.
If I add a line with an existing type of vegetable, will the cells merge together, knowing that there has already been a merger before?
If possible, I would like to understand your code in order to reproduce it later please.

Cordially.

Comment: @william I'm sorry for the inconvenience and my incomplete answer. I updated my answer by reflecting your next question. Please confirm it.

Comment: ,it's more me that is asked something incomplete and I apologize

Comment: @william How about my updated answer? If my updated answer was not useful for you, I'm really sorry. At that time, I would like to modify it.

Comment: I just saw your message, and I'm seeing how to use breakApart ()

Comment: @william I added the usage of ``breakApart()`` to my answer, please confirm it. If you have any questions, feel free to tell me.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, your code works fine, grzat thanms for your patience.