# Google sheets: automatically merge identical cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to merge cells that are vertically adjacent and have identical values.

```
|"X"|         |"X"|
|"X"|   --->  |   |
|"X"|         |   | (merged)
```

I am making a time-tracking sheet and to have similar activities merged would be awesome
[example image from my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHQup.png)
(So, "sleep" would be merged into one big block, and so would "tracking this sheet")

I only want to merge cells vertically

(also, I am operating only in the range of B26: H121)

I have tried to work with some existing code on stackoverflow for this — [Google Sheets - Horizontal merge identical cells in single row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53780869/google-sheets-horizontal-merge-identical-cells-in-single-row) and [Merge cells with same words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212749/merge-cells-with-same-words) — but I haven't been able to get anything to work. Maybe it's because I don't know javascript haha.

———

Also one last thing, if possible, I want to have someway of storing how large a merged cell is. (In the picture above it would be 16 and 4 for sleep and tracking this sheet, respectively.) This would allow me to track the time on any particular task when the cells are merged. (Maybe store this number in a note attached to the cell?)

Please help,
Paul

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Welcome. At the risk of repeating the comments of @Cooper, would you please edit your question to share the code that you have developed and highlight where the the errors are happening. Would you also share your spreadsheet. And since StackOverflow isn't a bespoke coding service, it may be best to defer some issues for another question.

Answer (score 2):

You can merge all vertical cells within a given range using the `merge()` method which is available to use on Range objects. You can see the documentation for how the `merge()` method works [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#merge).

The following code will merge cells vertically as long as they have the same non-empty value and they are adjacent to one another.

```
function numberToLetter(number){
  var temp = "" 
  var letter = "";
  while (number > 0){
    temp = (number - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    number = (number - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  for (col = 2; col <=8; col++){ //Do from Columns B to H (B = 2, H = 8)
    var start = 26; // Start row range
    var end = 121;  // End of Row range
    var mergeArr = [];
    var colData = ss.getRange(start, col, end, 1).getValues().toString().split(","); 
    var last = false;
    var count = -1;

    colData.forEach(function(e) {
      if (e == last){
        count++;
      }
      else if (e != last){
        mergeArr.push(count + 1);
        count = 0;
      }
      last = e;
    });

    var mergeStart = start;   
    for (each = 0; each < mergeArr.length; each++){

      var mergeEnd = mergeStart + mergeArr[each] - 1;      

      if (ss.getRange(numberToLetter(col) + mergeStart).getValue() == "" ){        
      }
      else{
        if (mergeEnd - mergeStart >= 1){
          ss.getRange(numberToLetter(col) + mergeStart + ':' + numberToLetter(col) + mergeEnd).merge(); 
        }
      }
      mergeStart = mergeEnd + 1;      
    }     
  }
}
```

You can modify this for any range by changing the values of `start`, `end`, and the range of `col` in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rafa Guillermo's solution was almost exactly what I wanted, but I made two minor changes: 1) I wanted to specify columns as an array (1-based indices) and 2) Some of my data includes commas in cells, which doesn't work well with the `toString().split(",")` approach.

```
function numberToLetter(number){
  var temp = "" 
  var letter = "";
  while (number > 0){
    temp = (number - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    number = (number - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}

function mergeColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  cols = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11]   
  var start = 1; // Start row range
  var end = 500;  // End of Row range

  cols.forEach( function (col) { // For each relevant column
    var mergeArr = [];
    var colData = ss.getRange(start, col, end, 1).getValues() 
    var last = null;
    var count = -1;

    colData.forEach(function(e) {
      eStr = e.toString()
      if (eStr === last){
        count++;
      } else {
        mergeArr.push(count + 1);
        count = 0;
      }
      last = eStr;
    });

    var mergeStart = start;   
    for (each = 0; each < mergeArr.length; each++){

      var mergeEnd = mergeStart + mergeArr[each] - 1;      

      if (ss.getRange(numberToLetter(col) + mergeStart).getValue() == "" ){        
      }
      else{
        if (mergeEnd - mergeStart >= 1){
          ss.getRange(numberToLetter(col) + mergeStart + ':' + numberToLetter(col) + mergeEnd).merge(); 
        }
      }
      mergeStart = mergeEnd + 1;      
    }     
  })
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('First item', 'mergeColumns')
      .addToUi();
}
```