# create a table with multiple cells in front of another in a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I need to create a table equal to the one in the image, I have the data in arrangements

[image]

I have only managed to create simple tables.

An example data array, and my code so far:

```
employees=[{    
  'factor':'Clientes',
  'caracteristica':'Tipo de Persona',
  'descripcion':'Posibilidad de que las personas naturales, juridicas..'
},{
  'factor':'Clientes',
  'caracteristica':'Tipo de Regimen',
  'descripcion':'Posibilidad de que los clientes incluidos...'
},{    
  'factor':'Clientes',
  'caracteristica':'Actividad Economica',
  'descripcion':'Posibilidad de que los clientes...'
},{
  'factor':'Productos y/o Servicios',
  'caracteristica':'Servicios',  
  'descripcion':'Posibilidad de que los distintos servicios ofrecidos '
},{
  'factor':'Productos y/o Servicios',
  'caracteristica':'Canales de distribucion',  
  'descripcion':'Posibilidad de que los canales....'
},{
  'factor':'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica':'Zona de Frontera',  
  'descripcion':'Presencia en Zonas de frontera con incidencias............'
},{
  'factor':'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica':'Zona de Produccion de Hoja de Coca',  
  'descripcion':'Presencia en Zonas para la produccion de hoja de coca.........'
},{
  'factor':'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica':'Zona de Minera',  
  'descripcion':'Presencia en Zonas con actividades...'
}];

function funcion2(employees) {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('some id');
  var nombre = ''
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var header = body.appendParagraph("Anexo 01");
  header.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)
    .editAsText().setFontSize(12);

  var header2 = body.appendParagraph("IDENTIFICACIÓN DE LOS RIESGOS DE LAFT Y RIESGOS ASOCIADOS");
  header2.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  body.appendParagraph("");
  var section = body.appendParagraph("Para identificar los riesgos de LAFT y riesgos asociados, de acuerdo con la clasificación y caracterización " + nombre + "-" + descripcion);
  section.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
  body.appendParagraph("");

  var tableCliente = body.appendTable();
  var tr1 = tableCliente.appendTableRow();
  var tb = tr1.appendTableCell("CLIENTE").setBackgroundColor("#84cdff");

  var table = body.appendTable();
  for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
    if (employees[i].factor == "CLIENTES") {
      var tr=table.appendTableRow();
      var tb = tr.appendTableCell(employees[i].caracteristica).setWidth(90);
      var tb = tr.appendTableCell(employees[i].descripcion);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Why do you want a script to do this. Why not just do it from the page editor?

Comment: Good new/bad news. I have some code that builds a document table, but there appear to be "issues" surrounding the merge aspect; or at least I am not bright enough to overcome them. Anyway, I suggest you bone up on merges in docs because this will be the missing component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure why you would want to use a script to do this. I would think it would be far more simple to create the table in the page editor.

- Open a blank document.
- From the main menu, Select Insert, Table, and specify 3 columns and 9 rows.
- Type the headings in all three columns in the first row.
- Type the content in the second and third columns for all the other rows.
- In the 1st column, select the 2nd, 3rd and 4th cells; right click and choose “Merge cells”
- In the 1st column, select the 5th and 6th cells; right click and choose “Merge cells”
- In the 1st column, select the 7th, 8th and 9th cells; right click and choose “Merge cells”.
- Enter the content in the three merged cells in column 1.
- Select any cell, right click, Choose “Table Properties”. Under Cell Vertical Alignment, select “Middle”.
- Select row 1 and change the Background colour to suit.

---

**SCRIPT OPTION**

The OP wants to create a table *by script*, a feature of which is the merging of certain "common" cells in the first column. The OP's code got as far as the header for the table.

There is not a great deal available to use a resource on the creation of tables in Google Docs. In addition, it's fairly evident that references to tables emphasis the "row-wise" aspects and events/commands based on columns are in short supply.

There are two options for the construction of the table content. In this code I've followed the OP's approach of looping through the Object and progressively updating the table with the content. An alternative would be to build a new array and then build the table from the array in much the same way that is described in the Google [Class Table documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table).

```
employees = [{
  'factor': 'Clientes',
  'caracteristica': 'Tipo de Persona',
  'descripcion': 'Posibilidad de que las personas naturales, juridicas..'
}, {
  'factor': 'Clientes',
  'caracteristica': 'Tipo de Regimen',
  'descripcion': 'Posibilidad de que los clientes incluidos...'
}, {
  'factor': 'Clientes',
  'caracteristica': 'Actividad Economica',
  'descripcion': 'Posibilidad de que los clientes...'
}, {
  'factor': 'Productos y/o Servicios',
  'caracteristica': 'Servicios',
  'descripcion': 'Posibilidad de que los distintos servicios ofrecidos '
}, {
  'factor': 'Productos y/o Servicios',
  'caracteristica': 'Canales de distribucion',
  'descripcion': 'Posibilidad de que los canales....'
}, {
  'factor': 'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica': 'Zona de Frontera',
  'descripcion': 'Presencia en Zonas de frontera con incidencias............'
}, {
  'factor': 'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica': 'Zona de Produccion de Hoja de Coca',
  'descripcion': 'Presencia en Zonas para la produccion de hoja de coca.........'
}, {
  'factor': 'Zona Geografica',
  'caracteristica': 'Zona de Minera',
  'descripcion': 'Presencia en Zonas con actividades...'
}];

function so5501193401() {

  //define header cell style which we will use while adding cells in header row
  //Background color, text bold, white
  var headerStyle = {};
  headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BACKGROUND_COLOR] = '#84cdff';
  headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  headerStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#FFFFFF';

  //Style for the cells other than header row
  var cellStyle = {};
  cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = false;
  cellStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.FOREGROUND_COLOR] = '#000000';

  //By default, each paragraph had space after, so we will change the paragraph style to add zero space
  //we will use it later
  var paraStyle = {};
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.SPACING_AFTER] = 0;
  paraStyle[DocumentApp.Attribute.LINE_SPACING] = 1;

  //setup the document reference
  var docid = "<<insert document id as a string>>";
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
  var body = doc.getBody();

  // build the document introduction
  var header = body.appendParagraph("Anexo 01");
  header.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER).editAsText().setFontSize(12);
  var header2 = body.appendParagraph("IDENTIFICACIÓN DE LOS RIESGOS DE LAFT Y RIESGOS ASOCIADOS");
  header2.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
  body.appendParagraph("");
  var section = body.appendParagraph("Para identificar los riesgos de LAFT y riesgos asociados, de acuerdo con la clasificación y caracterización");
  section.setAlignment(DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.JUSTIFY);
  body.appendParagraph("");

  // variables for the loop
  var factortext = "";
  var factorcounter = 0

  // build the header row of the table
  var table = body.appendTable();
  var tr = table.appendTableRow();
  var col1title = "Factores de riesgo";
  var col2title = "Caracteristica";
  var col3title = "Descripcion del Riesgo de LAFT";
  var th = tr.appendTableCell(col1title);
  th.setAttributes(headerStyle);
  var th = tr.appendTableCell(col2title);
  th.setAttributes(headerStyle);
  var th = tr.appendTableCell(col3title);
  th.setAttributes(headerStyle);

  // create a loop to work through the 'employees' object
  for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

    // add a row and define the cell contents
    var tr = table.appendTableRow();
    var factorname = employees[i].factor;
    var caraname = employees[i].caracteristica;
    var descname = employees[i].descripcion;

    //establish if this is the first row or not
    if (factorcounter != 0) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i: "+i+", record#"+(i+1));//DEBUG
      var factorname = employees[i].factor;
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: factor: "+factorname);//DEBUG

      // establish if this is the continuation or beginning of a new factor group
      if (factortext != factorname) { // this is a new group
        var td = tr.appendTableCell(factorname);
        td.setAttributes(cellStyle);
      } else {
        var td = tr.appendTableCell("");
      }

      factortext = factorname;
    }

    // establish if this is the first row of the table
    if (factorcounter == 0) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i: "+i+", record#1");//DEBUG
      var factorname = employees[i].factor;
      factortext = factorname;
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: factor: "+factorname);//DEBUG
      var td = tr.appendTableCell(factorname);
      td.setAttributes(cellStyle);
    }

    // increment the factor counter
    factorcounter++;

    // insert the characttics and description
    var td = tr.appendTableCell(caraname);
    td.setAttributes(cellStyle);
    var td = tr.appendTableCell(descname);
    td.setAttributes(cellStyle);

  }

}
```

---

Document screenshot

[image: Document screenshot]

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, the need to do it with a script is because the whole document will be created dynamically and the data will come from a database, and at that time I do not know how many rows or columns the table will have

Comment: not yet, I think that the creation of documents is still limited dynamically with google app script, or else I do not know more about its functions

Comment: I couldn't be certain one way or the other - I really work with spreadsheets (A LOT). But I'd be surprised if the task couldn't be done programmatically. I'm interested in helping you explore this. You said "_the data will come from a database_" What IS your data source?

Comment: I capture the data in an arrangement and there I show its structure (post edited and image route), what I want is a result equal to the photo, agrugar "factor", "caracteristica" and their "description"

Comment: Please populate "Employees" with a complete set of data. At present it doesn't correspond to the photo, and that makes things quite confusing.

Comment: @DannaLucianaCarrilloPerez Would you also prepare a document (manually) that would represent a successful outcome of the code?

Comment: thank you friend, you helped me a lot, I am relatively new and I would like to continue to meet people like you and somehow I will return it to the whole community, thank you!

Comment: @DannaLucianaCarrilloPerez I was sorry that I wasn't able to use your variable `nombre`; not that there wasn't a use for a counter, but I was intrigued to see where you might have taken it (so to speak). SO is about paying back and paying forward, I'm glad you have leaned that. If my answer has been useful, then you might consider accepting it.

Comment: @DannaLucianaCarrilloPerez I came across another topic that might be useful to you. Take a look at (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215702/1330560); its outcome is exactly what you are trying to achieve. The answer was written by Tanaike who is a VERY skilled coder.